# BTS fanfic where they have superpowers

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, music, powers

This was a fan-fiction story in which members of the K-pop group [BTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BTS_(band)) have superpowers.

it was Yoon-gi centric, where Yoon-gi is the leader. In the story, Yoon-gi was the 2nd youngest. The rest of the BTS members will be going to the academy to learn how to control their powers where Yoon-gi is already studying.

They don't meet Yoon-gi until the 2nd or 3rd chapter, and when they do meet him it's because of a class where they have to be divided into teams and class instructor puts the 7 of them together.

The only things they have heard about Yoon-gi are rumours. 
The students and even some teachers of the academy call him "The Shadow" because he is the only 17-year-old kid to have the highest control of their power and he is even better than their instructor

Also, Yoon-gi is the only one who has a lot of powers, although the seven members of BTS are among the rare ones who have more than three powers.

Comment: https://www.wattpad.com/story/119235747-freaks-bts-superpower-au? https://www.wattpad.com/story/149727096-unbelievable-bts-superpower-au? Something from https://www.tumblr.com/search/bts%20superpowers%20au?

Comment: We really need more details. I recommend going to https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fanfic-story-id-question and seeing if that helps prompt more details in your mind.

Comment: "2nd youngest" what?

Comment: What powers did he/they have?

Comment: Valorum I don't remember their powers

Comment: "Hyung" being "Older brother"?

Comment: And so it is different from the RL Yoon-gi, who is the youngest of two sons?